# gstreamer: How to use typefind - an example

Tags: plugins, gstreamer

Would like to see a working example of using typefind. Where we can dynamically add the gstreamer element to the source pad of gstreamer as explained in this [page](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-typefinding.html)

From that page

> Once a media type has been detected, you can plug an element (e.g. a
>   demuxer or decoder) to the source pad of the typefind element, and
>   decoding of the media stream will start right after.

Based on the statement above, Want to add a particular type of demuxer when a particular media stream has been identified?

Answer (score 0):

Auto-plugging elements like used in playbin will use typefind to probe the stream in order to select the right demuxer.
Common typefinders are registered here:

http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/gst/typefind/gsttypefindfunctions.c

But you can also do that in your own plugin.